# jQuery: Replace image size in filename

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, filepath

Input URL: `http://somewpsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMG_1234-150x150.jpg`
Expected Output URL: `http://somewpsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMG_1234.jpg`
Current Regex: `$(this).attr('src').replace('/-[\d]+x[\d]+/', '');`

Assume `$(this)` represents an `img` element. I know I could just as easily use `-150x150` as the replacement string, but there are different sizes and it should be capable of supported even more sizes without the need to come back and edit this code.

I'm hoping someone here can figure out what's wrong with my current regex above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong is that in JavaScript regex's aren't strings, so you don't wrap them in quotes.

Note that you don't need the brackets around the `\d`:

```
$(this).prop('src', function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(/-\d+x\d+\.jpg$/, '.jpg');
});
```

---

If you might also be using other image formats, use this instead:

```
$(this).prop('src', function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(/-\d+x\d+\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, '.$1');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are specific literals in JavaScript, they are not created as strings. Simply remove the single quotes:

```
$(this).attr('src').replace(/-[\d]+x[\d]+/, '')
```

Note that `replace` does not work in-place but returns the resultant string instead. So depending on whether you want to process it further or just write it back into the attribute, you will have to assign this to something.

Comment: -1 This is patently wrong. The new string is never applied to the `src`!

Comment: @JosephSilber of course not, I thought this question was simply about the regex, and not about the usage of `replace`. But maybe you're right. Judging by the semicolon in the OP's regex he might not know that `replace` does not work in-place. I added some clarification.